# Java - Get object of class depending on its name

Tags: java, class, object, field

this is my situation:

I have a method which has a String as parameter. This method has to receive an object from a class called Urls. The object it has to recieve, has the same name as the value of the String. Here is my code:

```
private Object getObject(String objectName){
    try
    {
        Field field = Urls.class.getField(objectName);          
    }
    catch (NoSuchFieldException e)
    {}
    catch (IllegalAccessException e)
    {}
}
```

And here is my Urls class:

```
public class Urls{

public static final String[] ASTUN = new String[]{
    "http://www.astun.com/camara/truchas.jpg",
    "https://www.todonieve.com/photowebcam.asp?fotografia=astun/astun.jpg",
    "http://www.astun.com/camara/caba%C3%B1a%20sarrios.jpg",
    "http://www.astun.com/camara/sector%20sarrios.jpg",
    "http://www.astun.com/camara/sector%20raca%20prad.jpg",
    "http://www.astun.com/camara/sector%20aguila%20cr.jpg",
    "http://www.astun.com/camara/sector%20truchas.jpg",
    "http://www.astun.com/camara/sector%20llanos%20.jpg",
    "http://www.astun.com/camara/llegada.jpg",
    "http://www.astun.com/camara/terraza.jpg",
    "http://www.astun.com/camara/panoramica.jpg",
    "http://www.astun.com/camara/snow.jpg"
};

private static final String[] CANDANCHU = new String[]{
    "https://www.todonieve.com/photowebcam.asp?fotografia=candanchu/candanchu.jpg",
    "https://www.todonieve.com/photowebcam.asp?fotografia=CandanchuNew/CandanchuNew.jpg",
    "https://www.todonieve.com/photowebcam.asp?fotografia=candanchu_rinconada/candanchu_rinco.jpg",
"https://www.todonieve.com/photowebcam.asp?fotografia=candanchu_tobazo/candanchu_tobazo.jpg"
};

}
```

So, that way I have a Field object, but how can I get the String[] of that field? I have read about the get(Object object) method of Field class but it seems that i doesnt do what I want to do...

EDIT: I WANT TO GET ASTUN OR CANDACHU STRING ARRAYS

Comment: Objects don't have "names". Do you mean the variable? If so, that gives the code a code smell. Do you want to create a Map perhaps? Note that your Urls class contains nothing but static arrays of Strings. What's the purpose of getting a String with a String?

Comment: Can you give an example of what you would expect the result to be?

Comment: +Hovercraft Full Of Eels well I meant one of the fields... The String passed as parameter will contain "ASTUN" or "CANDANCHU"

Comment: Can you better describe the problem that this code is trying to solve, not the code solution that you're attempting to use. This smells all wrong to me and I wonder if there is a better way of going about solving the overall problem, that maybe you're barking up the wrong tree.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will need something like this:

```
private Object getObject(String objectName){
    try
    {
        Field field = Urls.class.getField(objectName);
        Object o = field.get(null); // null works as well.
        return o;
    }
    catch (NoSuchFieldException e)
    { e.printStackTrace(); }
    catch (IllegalAccessException e)
    { e.printStackTrace(); }
}

private String[] getStringArray(String arrayName)
{
    return (String[]) getObject(arrayName);
}
```

Usage:

```
Object o = getObject("ASTUN");
// or:
String[] arr = getStringArray("ASTUN");
```

Comment: How did you get to that conclusion? OP says he gets the `Field`, so that isn't the problem here.

Comment: Well this worked for me... The reason I decided to ask this question was the paremeter of th Field.get() method, passing 'this' worked for me .Also I used getField() insted of getDeclaredField() as you said thanks

Comment: I edited my answer. `null` works as well. In fact, `null` is more correct, because the field is static.

Answer (score 3):

Avoid reflection whenever possible. It often does more harm than good.

Put them into a map:

```
public class Urls {
  //put your arrays here

  private static final Map<String,String[]> urlsLists = new HashMap<>();
  static {
    urlLists.put("ASTUN", ASTUN);
    urlLists.put("CANDANCHU", CANDANCHU);
  }

  public static String[] getUrlList(String name) {
    return urlLists.get(name);
  }
}
```

And then call it like this:

```
private Object getObject(String objectName){
  return Urls.getUrlList(objectName);
}
```

**Update**

You loose a lot of nice stuff Java help you with, including type-safety, encapsulation and compile-time checks. Because of this it is a lot more error prone. There is a much increased risk of run-time errors and you need a bunch of extra code to handle this. Your brief example already have two catch clauses. Trust me - that will just get worse.

You can even improve type-safety more by creating an Enum to define url-types. Then you will get compile time checks that you have spelled the name right and even auto-completion all through-out your code. :)

```
public class Urls {
  public enum UrlTypes {ASTUN; CANDANCHU;}
  // ..
  private static final Map<UrlTypes,String[]> urlsLists = new HashMap<>();
  static {
    urlLists.put(UrlTypes.ASTUN, ASTUN);
    urlLists.put(UrlTypes.CANDANCHU, CANDANCHU);
  }
  ..
  public static String[] getUrlList(UrlTypes name) {
    return urlLists.get(name);
  }
}
```

Every error you can catch at compile-time instead of at run-time can save you between half an hour or half a week of work, when things get complex.

Comment: Why should I avoid reflexion?? Thanks for your answer

Comment: @BamsBamx: because 1) it is slow. 2) it makes you hard-code things into your code unnecessarily making your code more rigid and less extensible. 3) It is a very low-level solution exposing internals and this increases its danger of producing hard to debug errors. 4) Your IDE is blind to reflection, making it very hard to refactor code. Sure use reflection when the task calls for it, and especially when it requires it, but this scenario is not the case.

Comment: Agreeing with Hovercraft. Have expanded the answer.

Answer (score 1):

`getField` will return the (reflexive) representation of the field concept in the `Urls` class.  You then need to bind it with an actual object of that class to have access to the contents of the field in that object.

```
Field field = Urls.class.getFiled(objectName);
String[] values = (String[]) field.get(o);
```

where `o` is a variable of type `Urls`.

Note the cast to `String[]` as `Field.get()` will return an `Object` as it does not know the actual type. You should make sure that the type is indeed correct by using the `Field.getType()` method and compare that to `Urls.class`.

Comment: @BamsBamx - true, miss that the fields were `static`

Answer (score 0):

Since objects dont have names, you will need to create ypur own class, put the field variable in there, then use that instead of Object. Or use a Map for better key/value logging.